# How to Join two tables by extracting date and hour separately?

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
select 
    s.RollNumber, s.[Payment Date], s.Amount, h.HourKey, d.Year 
from 
    [Accounts].[dbo].StudentFeesDetails s
inner join  
    [ABCU_DWH].[dbo].DimHourOFTheDay h on h.HourKey = DATEPART(Hour, s.[Payment Date])
inner join 
    [ABCU_DWH].[dbo].DimDates d on d.[Full Date] = s.[Payment Date]  
where 
    RollNumber = 5
```

`s.[Payment Date]` is a column of `Datetime` datatype. The query does not produce any results. By commenting one join statement the query produces results. So what is the problem in this code?

Comment: if commenting a given join statement produces results, the join condition is therefore failing. The equivalence ( field 1 = field 2) you want to happen does not exist for the existing records in the tables involved.

Comment: Yes, You were right. Commenting does not solve the problem. I worked according to the given advice and it solves the problem of equivalance. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `s.[Payment Date]` is a datetime value it has a time component too, and the reason you're not getting any data back might be that the time part doesn't match the value of `[Full Date]` (which I assume is a date).

Try casting it to a date:

```
inner join [ABCU_DWH].[dbo].DimDates d
on d.[Full Date] = cast(s.[Payment Date] as date)
```

If `[Full Date]` is a datetime you might have to cast that too, so that you end up comparing the date part only like so:

```
on cast(d.[Full Date] as date) = cast(s.[Payment Date] as date)
```

Comment: Yes, You imagine the Right Scenario. Thank you very much for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to compare datetime with date in second join
Try to change:

```
inner join [ABCU_DWH].[dbo].DimDates d
on d.[Full Date] = s.[Payment Date]
```

To next:

```
inner join [ABCU_DWH].[dbo].DimDates d
on CAST(d.[Full Date] AS DATE) = CAST(s.[Payment Date] AS DATE)
```

Comment: Absolutely Right Answer Given By All Respondents. It effectively solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: if stepan's answer is right, give him at least an upvote.

Comment: Problem is we have 2 answers that are almost exactly the same.